# Creating big number of arrary in blender

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, scale

I am trying to make visual comparison of money stacked upon each other in group of 100 notes(bills).

In screen shot, small stack on left is \$100 and on right it is \$1 million which i created through array modifier.

The problem is i have to make it till billions and already, my system is running out of memory.

Please suggest me a good technique for it (give bit details as i am newbie). Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why are you using real, individual notes meshes? It **will** be memory intensive, and in your case it's also a waste of resources because the notes show no variation. It looks artificial. I'd introduce some variations to the notes (rotation, creases, etc) then I'd use microdisplacement on a cube of the size of the desired stack. I'm working on something similar, a chain mail texture made from individual chain links. I'll update my [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88856/how-to-bake-proper-alpha-maps) later today, it might give you some ideas on how approach your issue.

Comment: I concur with @Nihal, an old rule for 3d is not to waste resources in what is not visible. What you need is very simple geometry and even cleverer texturing.

Comment: as i have told i am a beginner, i don't know much of this stuff nihal is talking about but what i have works with me. I want to keep it less complicated (as much as i can)

Comment: If you are really going the single objects road, then use instances instead, or perhaps particle system, and benefit from memory optimization, otherwise it will quickly become unpractical.

Answer (score 1):

Create a single cube, scaled to the size you want to represent.  UV unwrap the cube. Add an image texture of the bill you want to use and set its scaling to match the number of bills you want across and along the surface.

Comment: That i what i thought of doing and seems a perfect solution. As i am trying to keep measurements very accurate, can I convert this stack to single big cube? please guide me about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with UV and stuff, use Array to create the top layer of notes, and use Cube to model the sides. Blender can not magically skip all items inside the pile without calculating if they are visible, and that calculation takes time.