# How can I make texture repeat 'n' times in blender

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to repeat the uv mapped texture by precisely 'n' times without using array etc. How can it be done?

Comment: Do you want to fit the texture for n times on the same object? Or do you also want to repeat the mesh?

Comment: i want to fit the texture n times on same object. no repetition of mesh

Comment: But repetition of texture?

Comment: Try to go into uv editor, select all your mesh, press 's', plus the factor n

Comment: @Quacksilber actually i am try to do what i have describe in this question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88961/creating-big-number-of-arrary-in-blender
your help will be highly appriciated

Comment: Use the Min and Max values of the mapping node. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21175/how-to-make-a-image-repeat-in-cycles/21208#21208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Min and Max Values of the vector mapping node:

[image]